# Python 'with' command

Tags: python, with-statement

Is this code

```
with open(myfile) as f:
    data = f.read()
    process(data)
```

equivalent to this one

```
try:
    f = open(myfile)
    data = f.read()
    process(f)
finally:
    f.close()
```

or the following one?

```
f = open(myfile)
try:
    data = f.read()
    process(f)
finally:
    f.close()
```

This article: http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm suggests (if I understand it correctly) that the latter is true. However, the former would make more sense to me. If I am wrong, what am I missing?

Comment: It's not equivalent to either. What if `process` raises an error? `with` does not handle errors here, but the other two do.

Comment: @ajcr: neither does `try:...finally:`. The second stanza is equivalent.

Comment: My mistake. I somehow read `except` when it wasn't there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's equivalent to the latter one, because until `open()` successfully returns, `f` has no value, and should not be closed.

Comment: `with` will always close the file for you. How does the second example do that?

Comment: @agconti If `open()` fails, the file was never opened, so it doesn’t need to be closed either.

Comment: @agconti If `open()` raises an exception, `f` is never even initialized. Not only that there is no reason to close `f`, but `f.close()` would raise `NameError: name 'f' is not defined` if you tried.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [documentation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/):

> A new statement is proposed with the syntax:
>
> ```
> with EXPR as VAR:
>     BLOCK
> ```
>
> The translation of the above statement is:
>
> ```
> mgr = (EXPR)
> exit = type(mgr).__exit__  # Not calling it yet
> value = type(mgr).__enter__(mgr)
> exc = True
> try:
>     try:
>         VAR = value  # Only if "as VAR" is present
>         BLOCK
>     except:
>         # The exceptional case is handled here
>         exc = False
>         if not exit(mgr, *sys.exc_info()):
>             raise
>         # The exception is swallowed if exit() returns true
> finally:
>     # The normal and non-local-goto cases are handled here
>     if exc:
>         exit(mgr, None, None, None)
> ```

And this is an extended version of your *second* code snippet. Initialization goes before `try ... finaly` block.