# Need understanding of this python error

Tags: python, if-statement, text

I am actually processing a text log file, with the following python code. this runs continuosly even after the mline reaches EOF.

```
myfile = open("560A_HL_Japan_02_04_2016.txt", 'r')
mod_myfile = open("560A_HL_Japan_02_04_2016_modified.txt", "wb")
mfl = myfile.readlines()
mstring=''
for mline in mfl:
    mli = mline.split()
    for l in range(len(mli)):
        if l >= 2:                      #second object
            mstring += mli[l]+' '
    mstring += '\n'
    mod_myfile.write(mstring)
mod_myfile.close()
```

If I make a slight modification with the below code. it executes without any issues

```
myfile = open("560A_HL_Japan_02_04_2016.txt", 'r')
mod_myfile = open("560A_HL_Japan_02_04_2016_modified.txt", "wb")
mfl = myfile.readlines()
for mline in mfl:
    mli = mline.split()
    for l in range(len(mli)):
        if l == 2:                      #second object
            mstring = mli[l]+' '
        elif l > 2:
            mstring += mli[l]+' '
    mstring += '\n'
    mod_myfile.write(mstring)
 mod_myfile.close()
```

Comment: Are you sure this runs continuously and not `mstring` just grows all the time? If the first snippet you initialise it once outside the loops, but in the second you initialise it every line. Can we have a small sample of the file? By the way, you can simplify all your loops down to `data = '\n'.join(' '.join(line.split()[1:]) for line in mfl.readlines())` and write that to your output file. You should also consider reading from/writing to your files with the [`with`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34382253/python-with-command) syntax.

Comment: @Reti43 i wouldn't do the second join with the new line. Op is already having problems with a slow down implying there is a considerable amount of data. Strings in CPython have a micro optimisation whereby if the string only has one reference then `+=` will be done in place rather than creating a new string. Still better to use join, but good to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first example, you initialise `mstring` as the empty string outside of your loops:

`mstring = ''`

Then in the loop you keep adding to `mstring`:

`mstring += mli[l]+' '`

but `mstring` is never reinitialised, so it keeps getting bigger and bigger, so the code will take longer and longer to execute.

In your second example, `mstring` is reset every time `l` is equal to 2:

```
if l == 2:                      #second object
    mstring = mli[l]+' '
```

Because `mstring` is reset from time to time the second example performs better.

A couple of other observations:

Using += to add strings is not guaranteed to give best performance in all versions of Python.  Consider building a list and calling ''.join() when it is complete.

Don't use `l` as a variable name, it looks like 1 in some fonts.